# SQL: update a record if a certain kind of a record is not in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update a certain record of a table only if certain another record does not already exist in the table.

I tried a SQL similar to following.

```
update mytable
     set val = 'someval'
     where id = 'someid' and
           0 = (select count(*) from mytable where col='val2');
```

This fails with following error.

`You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause`

Only one process is updating this table, so preserving the atomicity of the operation is not necessary.

I know I can do this using two SQL queries, but is there a way to do this in a single query?

Comment: So is it the same table or not the same?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel it is the same table

Comment: Can you do `where id = 'someid' and exists(select * from mytable where col='val2')`

Comment: @Jeff, still the same error (can't specify target table for update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are referring to the same table, the best way to do this uses `LEFT JOIN`:

```
update mytable t left join
       mytable t2
       on t2.col = 'val2'
    set val = 'someval'
    where t.id = 'someid' and t2.col is null;
```

Comment: this is it..beat me to it

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.  Here's one option using a subquery with `not exists`:

```
update mytable 
set val = 'someval' 
where id = 'someid' 
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from (select * from mytable) t
    where col = 'val2')
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04fa2/1)

Using the subquery bypasses the error you are receiving.  Other approaches include `outer join` with `null` checks or using `not in` -- depends a bit on the data.

Answer (score 0):

TRY this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET val = 'someval' 
WHERE id = 'someid' AND col <> 'val2'
```